# Mocking LambdaClient not working correctly

Tags: java, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mockito, junit5

I am trying to write a unit test for the below method , where it is invoking the Lambda.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.LambdaClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.InvokeResponse;

public class RoutingService {

  private LambdaClient lambdaClient;

  private String env;
  private String region;

  public RoutingService(){
     this.env = System.getenv(ENVIRONMENT);
     this.region = System.getenv(REGION);
     lambdaClient =  LambdaClient.builder().build();
  }

  public RoutingResponse invokeLambda(InvokeLambda request)  throws IOException {
    
    RoutingResponse invokeResponse = new RoutingResponse();

    String payload = createPayload(request);  // Some utility method
    String routingURI = getRoutingURI() ;  // Another utility method

    SDKBytes payloadBytes = SdkBytes.fromUtf8String(payload);

    InvokeRequest invokeRequest = InvokeRequest.builder()
                                  .functionName(routingUri)
                                  .payload(payloadBytes)
                                  .invocationType(INVOCATION_TYPE)   //  INVOCATION_TYPE  is caonstant = RequestResponse
                                  .build();

    try{
          InvokeResponse result;
          result = lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest);  //   Was trying to Mock this
          String resultString = result.payload().asUtf8String();
          invokeResponse = new ObjectMapper().readValue(resultString, RoutingResponse.class);
    }catch(AWSServiceExceptuion ex) {
          logger.error(new ErrorEvent(ex.awsErrorDetails.errorMessage(), ex.getMessage(), routingUri));
          invokeResponse.setStatusCode(ex.statusCode());
          invokeResponse.setBody(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return response;
 }
```

I am trying to write unit test case for this method as below (Mocking the LambdaClient) .
But still it is trying to call the invoke method of Lambda Client.
Means Mocking is not working properly .

```
public class RoutingServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private LambdaClient lambdaClient;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  void invokeLambda() throws IOException, JSONException {

    Map<String,String> queryStringParameters = new HashMap<>();
    queryStringParameters.put("test","GOOG");

    String[] cookies = {"cookiea", "cookieb"};

    Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("header1","valuex");
    headers.put("header2","valuey");

    InvokeLambda fakeRequest = new InvokeLambda.InvokeLambdaBuilder()
                               .cdnToken("cdn-token").applicationName("eaf-4137-demo")
                               .service("quote").method("GET")
                               .path("QuoteService/getQuote")
                               .queryString(queryStringParameters)
                               .headers(headers)
                               .cookies(cookies)
                               .body("body")
                               .requestId("request-id")
                               .build();

      InvokeResponse fakeResponse = InvokeResponse.builder().build();  //  This class belongs to AWS library
      
      Mockito.when(lambdaClient.invoke(Mockito.any(InvokeRequest.class))).thenReturn(fakeResponse); //  This is not working correctly ..

      RoutingService routingService = new RoutingService();
      RoutingResponse response = routingService.invokeLambda(fakeRequest);

      Assertions.assertTrue(response.getStatusCode()==200);

   }
}
```

When I run this test , an Exception is thrown in the try{} block of 'RoutingService' class , because we are passing a dummy "cdn token"
in fakeResponse.
Ideally , it should not invoke the lambda as we are Mocking it.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here ?
How to correct this ?

Comment: Please be specific on what the exact error is, and what you have tried to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your `lambdaClient` mock in your instance of `RoutingService`. In dead your mock is created in your test setup but you create a new instance of RoutingService that will create its own instance of lambdaClient not the mock you created in your test.
I suggest to update your RoutingService to allow constructor dependency injection:

```java
 public RoutingService(final LambdaClient lambdaClient){
     this.env = System.getenv(ENVIRONMENT);
     this.region = System.getenv(REGION);
     this.lambdaClient =  lambdaClient;
  }
```

And test like:

```java
RoutingService routingService = new RoutingService(lambdaClient);
RoutingResponse response = routingService.invokeLambda(fakeRequest);
```